# ASP.NET Routing a sub-page using a path parameter causes 404 for CSS/JS Files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a main page called: `/customers` where all the customer details are shown. However I would like to route my page named `"add-customer.aspx"` to be visited with the path `customers/add-customer`.

This is what I've tried:

**Global.asax:**

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "add-customer",
            "customers/add-customer",
            "~/add-customer.aspx"
        );
    }
}
```

However, when I visit `customers/add-customer`, this is what I get:

[image]

The console shows all the stylesheets and JS as 404:

[image]

I've declared them like I have in my other pages:

```
<!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
<link href="Content/vendors/morris.js/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Toggles CSS -->
<link href="Content/vendors/jquery-toggles/css/toggles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="Content/vendors/jquery-toggles/css/themes/toggles-light.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This is what my folder structure looks like:

[image]

Have I routed my page correctly and do I need to change the way the JS and CSS files are referenced when creating a subpage such as this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the way you have imported your css like belwo, then the UI will fix automatically --

```
<!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
<link href="~/Content/vendors/morris.js/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Toggles CSS -->
<link href="~/Content/vendors/jquery-toggles/css/toggles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="~/Content/vendors/jquery-toggles/css/themes/toggles-light.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And to work with routing, please re-arrange the in RegisterRoutes method --

```
private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "add-customer",
        "customers/add-customer",
        "~/add-customer.aspx"
    );
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```